# Can you replay phone calls?

Tags: grand-theft-auto-v

I am in the habit of bashing the <kbd>X</kbd> (PS3) or <kbd>A</kbd> (Xbox) button while on foot to sprint, or using it to break instead of <kbd>R1</kbd> when in a vehicle.

This habit causes me to frequently hangup on people just after they have called me. Is there a way to replay these lost calls without restarting a mission (which wouldn't work on random/non-mission calls anyway)?

Comment: I don't know if you can replay them but, you can check out the dialogue in the "Brief" section in the pause menu.

Comment: @Gmoneyrocks not if you were in the middle of a phone call, when yet another a-hole decides to run you over with his effing car >:(

Comment: Isn't it O (PS3) or B (Xbox) to hang up/Decline?

Answer (score 2):

In most cases if you hang up during a mission they will try to contact you via call or send you a text message. As for non-mission calls there's no way to replay them unfortunately.

Answer (score -1):

You can't replay the call, but if it's an important call from a main game character, the character will always try to call again in 5-10 minutes until you DO pick-up, so this shouldn't be a problem.

Comment: The problem isn't that he doesn't pick up though.  The problem is that if he's sprinting (tapping X/A repeatedly) then he will answer and hang up before he realises.  The call has been made.

Answer (score -1):

I am sure you can replay missions by going to the start menu and then there should be a journal or something and from there you should be able to find all of the missions from campaign. If your playing online just go to where you start the mission and enter it on foot.

Comment: Unless you know for sure, please don't post speculation. Telling someone "there should be something there that lets you do it" does not really answer the question.